# .htaccess to web config conversion

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

can anyone help me to convert this .htaccess file to web.config IIS. I have tried with some online tools also but still not working.

The server is windows 10and IIS version 7

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on

# deal with admin first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/<foldername>/(admin)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<foldername>/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<foldername>/backend/web/(assets|js)/ 
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/<foldername>/(admin)  
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/<foldername>/(assets|css) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/<foldername>/(assets|js) 
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<foldername>/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<foldername>/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<foldername>/download/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<foldername>/fonts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

Could you help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below rules:

```
<rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^admin/assets/(.*)$"  />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/assets/{R:1}"  />
</rule>

<rule name="rule2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*$"  />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/backend/web/index.php"  />
</rule>

<rule name="rule3" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^assets/(.*)$"  />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/frontend/web/assets/{R:1}"  />
</rule>

<rule name="rule4">
  <match url="^.*$"  />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/frontend/web/index.php"  />
</rule>
```

And here is a microsoft article on the equivalent components: [Translate .htaccess Content to IIS web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).